# Difference between ./executable and . executable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, executable

In a shell, what is the difference between?

```
. executable
```

and

```
./executable
```

In the first one, the dot a shortcut for [`source`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdln_source.htm) right? So is there a difference between `./executable` and `source executable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a difference between ./executable and source executable?

basic difference is,

```
./foo.sh      - foo.sh will be executed in a sub-shell
source foo.sh - foo.sh will be executed in current shell
```

some example could help to explain the difference:

let's say we have `foo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=100
```

source it:

```
$ source foo.sh 
$ echo $VAR
100
```

if you :

```
./foo.sh
$ echo $VAR
[empty]
```

another example, `bar.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello!"
exit 0
```

if you execute it like:

```
$ ./bar.sh
hello
$
```

but if you source it:

```
$ source bar.sh
<your terminal exits, because it was executed with current shell>
```

Comment: Are you sure a "sub-shell"?  Isn't it a child process?  The file might not be a shell script, so how could it be a sub-shell?

Answer (score 7):

`./executable` runs an executable which is in the current working directory. (`executable` is not enough for that if there is no `.` in your `$PATH`, and usually there isn't). In this case, `executable` can be an elf binary, or a script starting with `#!/some/interpreter`, or anything you can `exec` (on Linux it's potentially *everything*, thanks to `binfmt` module).

`. executable` sources a *shell script* into your current shell, whether it has *execute* permissions or not. No new process is created. In `bash`, script is searched according to the `$PATH` variable. Script may set environment variables which will remain set in *your* shell, define functions and aliases and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In the second one you give the path: `./` is the current working directory so it doesn't search in `PATH` for the executable but in the current directory.

`source` takes the executable as a parameter and executes it in the current process.

Comment: Is that why it is preferred to use ./executable, because you don't want to run in the possibility executing a another executable?

Comment: `source` does not start a child process.

Comment: You can source a file in current directory with . ./executable.

Comment: @choroba corrected source forces execution in the current process you are right